# Does it make sense to use $scope into a a $watch callback?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I use a popup component from [Semantic-UI](http://semantic-ui.com/) on my website.

This popup is used to show errors from the server, so most of the time it is hidden.
This popup is attached to a div I manage with `ng-show`. I need to initialize my popup component into a watcher (when my div is showned), because my popup can calculate its position only if its attached element is rendered.

While making some tests I notice that modification on the `$scope` from a `$watch` callback arn't applied:

```
$scope.$watch('shown', function () {
    //console.log('The click is detected')
    jQuery('#smthg').one('click', function () {
        console.log('I come here')
        $scope.shownBis = false //
    }) //*/
})
```

Have no effect on:

```
    <p ng-show="shownBis">This should be disappear</p>
```

([a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fractaliste/HB7LU/3249/))

I'm quite new in Angular and don't understand this behaviour, what happened and why Angular's philosophy doesn't allow it?

Answer (score 2):

Try [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) instead:

```
$scope.smthg = function () {
        $scope.shownBis = false;
  };
```

Your HTML:

```
<p ng-show="shown" ng-click="smthg()">Then click here</p>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/J8QWv/)

> While making some tests I notice that modification on the $scope from
>   a $watch callback arn't applied

BTW, your code also has problem with `.one()` inside the $watch as it will **attach more event handlers** whenever the `shown` changes and **not call the function**

Comment: Please note that `ng-click` has not the same effect as `.one()`.

Comment: @zeroflagL: Thanks for the comment, I knew that. I just mean we should use `ng-click` instead of `one` in this case. We could use a `flag` variable to achieve the same effect as `one` using `ng-click`

Answer (score 1):

You need to call $scope.$apply since you are no longer in an angular flow (passed flow to jQuery).

Wrap your change to the scope variables in $scope.$apply like this:

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.shownBis = false;
});
```

working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Hojou/UfA22/1/